# can access webcam but cannot display it into div

Tags: webrtc

This is a simple script I use:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#myVideo {
    background-color:#CCC;  
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    border:1px solid #000;  

  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="myVideo" autoplay></div> 

<script>
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream){
        $('#myVideo').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));

      }, function(){ 
        alert("error");
     });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have no error at all. It asks me to authorize webcam access, I accept, webcam switches on, but `#myVideo` div remains blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divs don't have a `src` attribute, you need to use the video element instead.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/g3ww83yu/

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<div id="myVideo" autoplay></div>
```

to this:

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay></video>.
```

Note that you can also apply global styles to your video elements, eg:

```
video {
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```